# Line graphs in R Help Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am currently plotting data from a excel sheet using R. The problem I am having is in regards to the legend. Here is the Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Key98.jpg As you can see in the legend, the values go as follows: PP1, PP10, PP15, PP3, PP30, PP5. I have been trying to make it go in numerical order as PP1, PP3, PP5, PP10,PP15, PP30. I am not sure how to fix this problem as I am very new to R coding. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! This is how i have my Excel sheet formated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfNaY.jpg Here is my Code:

```
library("dplyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library("tidyverse")
install.packages('reshape')
library('reshape')

    # import data
    NPPdata <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\rrami\\Desktop\\R-Data\\NPPdata.csv", header = TRUE)

    ggplot(NPPdata , aes(x = N_Gradient, y=Values, colour = Group))+
          geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Values-Stdvalue, ymax=Values+Stdvalue), lwd =1.2)+
          geom_line(lwd=1.5)+
          ggtitle("Year 1 MONO Phrag [Branch Prob 0.1]")+
          theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust =0.5)) +
          labs(x = "N-Gradient", y ="INV%")+
           theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16))
```

Comment: I've added a new answer. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example with "iris". As you can see, on the second figure 'scale_fill_discrete' is used to change the order of the labels

```
library (tidyverse)

data(iris)

figure_1 <- iris %>% 
  gather(key = floral_components, value = values, -Species) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = floral_components, y = values, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  labs(x = "Floral Components",
        y = "Values", 
        fill = "Species")
```

[image]

```
figure_2 <- iris %>% 
  gather(key = floral_components, value = values, -Species) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = floral_components, y = values, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  labs(x = "Floral Components",
       y = "Values", 
       fill = "Species") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("versicolor", "virginica", "setosa"))
```

[image]